# obtener valor fuera de evento click con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone

¿Cómo puedo obtener la variable documento fuera del clcik?

```
obtenerDocu: function() {

    $('#documentos-table tr').click(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
        documento = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();    
    });
    return documento; //null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo porqué tienes el código de inicialización del Evento click dentro de la misma función obtenerDocu con la que quieres obtener el valor del último click del primer elemento de la fila.

Deberías declarar el evento click, una vez cargada la tabla o el documento.

Te dejo un ejemplo de lo que creo que quieres hacer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#documentos-table tr').click...
});
```

A no ser que el evento click no la quieras tener activada desde un inicio.

```js
var obj = {
  docu: null,
  setDocu: function(value) {
    this.docu = value;
  },
  getDocu: function() {
    return this.docu;
  }
};

$('#documentos-table tr').click(function(e) {
   obj.setDocu($(this).find(':first-child').text());
   console.log(obj.getDocu());
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="documentos-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Dentro de obtenerDocu() hay una función click porque quiero llamar a obtenerDocu desde otra función

Comment: deleteDocument: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#modalBorrarDoc').modal('show') ; 
        this.obtenerDocu();
    }

Comment: ¿Se abre un modal con la tabla dentro? ¿Cual es la finalidad de todo esto?

Comment: no, la tabla está fuera de la modal. La modal sólo tiene un un botón "Eliminar" ¿Podría obtener el valor de una fila de la tabla desde la modal?

Comment: ¿Entonces es una tabla, y cuando haces click en una fila, quieres mostrar un modal para eliminar dicho documento de la base de datos o donde sea? Y necesitas acceder a la ID del documento desde deleteDocument. ¿es así?

Comment: Exacto, éso es. Disculpa, quizás no he dado datos suficientes. Quiero obtener el idDocumento para luego realizar una llamada ajax que borre dicho documento

Comment: Si fuese un formulario y no una tabla con formData podría obtener el atributo name... pero al ser una tabla no se me ocurre como obtener el valor de de la fila. No se si ésto aclara mi pregunta o lo empeora... disculpas.

Comment: La tabla entiendo que es dinamica, osea que la generas tu mediante código. Lo que podrías hacer es añadir un atributo a cada tr, por ejemplo <tr data-doc-id="ID_VALUE"><td>ID_VALUE</td>... y despúes al hacer click en la fila (tr), obtener el valor mediante el atributo del tr en vez de buscar el primer td del tr clicado...etc y entonces guardar el valor en una variable dentro del objeto como hago en mi ejemplo. Después mediante obj.getDoc() puedes obtener la ID.

Answer (score 1):

No podras de esa manera porque hay que esperar a que se haga clic por lo menos la primera vez sobre el elemento  `$('#documentos-table tr')` para asignar el valor.

La solucion que puedo visualizar es preguntar si el documento a sido selecionado, de lo contrario se le indicara al usuario que debe seleccionar un documento:

```
var doc = obtenerDocu();
if(doc == null || doc == undefined){
   alert("Seleccione un documento");
}
else{
  //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar la variable fuera del "eventhandler", pero tu función tendrá que tener en cuenta que mientras no se haya hecho ningún click, esa variable no tendrá un valor válido:

```js
$(() => {
  let lastClicked;
  $('button').click(function () {
     lastClicked=this.id;
  });
  
  function getLastClickedId() {
    if (lastClicked) {
      console.log(`El último botón pulsado fue ${lastClicked}`);
      if (lastClicked=='ko') {
        clearInterval(interv);
      }
    }
  };
  
  let interv=setInterval(getLastClickedId,1000);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ok"> OK </button>
<button id="ko"> KO </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es mala idea declarar un listener dentro de una función que llamarás varias veces, porque tendrás muchos listeners.

Además, si tu tabla tiene encabezados, debieras restringir el listener a los `td` que están dentro de `tbody`.

Ahora, supongamos que de todos modos quieres que `documento` tenga un valor antes del click. Una manera sería inicializar su valor como si alguien hubiese pinchado la primera fila:

(copiando la respuesta de [Pablo Lozano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22851/pablo-lozano)) pincha el botón antes de haber pinchado en la tabla:

```js
var documento = $('#documentos-table tbody').find('td').first().text();

function getDocumento() {
  console.log('documento actual es ', documento);
  return documento;
}

$('#documentos-table tbody tr').click(function(e) {
  documento = $(this).find('td').first().text();
  getDocumento();
});

$('#verdocumento').on('click', getDocumento);
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="verdocumento">Ver documento actual</button>
<table id="documentos-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```